# decision trees from features of multiple datatypes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm trying to construct a decision tree with scikit-learn's `DecisionTreeClassifier`. My data has numeric features consisting of integers and float values.

When constructing the decision tree, the integer features get converted 
to float.

For eg: if A is a feature that can only have integer values from 1-12, splitting criterion such as "A < 5.5" or "A < 3.1" come up in the tree. I don't want float value splitting criteria for A.

The depth of the tree increases if integer features get converted to float. How do I restrict integer features being converted to float?

Also, scikit-learn's `DecisionTreeClassifier` doesn't allow categorical features. Are there any alternative packages/libraries for constructing decision trees which allow Categorical Features?

Comment: Typically one hot encoding is used on the categorical features before building the decision tree. Are you using Pandas? Would you like an example?

Comment: No i'm not using Pandas. I'd like an example. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding integer vs floating point for decision trees, it does not matter for building a tree. Any split between two consecutive integers will be equivalent. It will never make two splits between the same pair of consecutive integers, because by doing so, one of the leaves will have no samples. It will generate an equivalent model regardless if integers or floats are used.

Using scikit-learn you are able to use categorical features using a `LabelBinarizer`. This will create a matrix of dummy values (one hot encoded) for the categories.

Here is an example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np
```

Define features

```
month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Mar']
day = [1, 15, 30, 5]
```

Define category targets

```
y = [0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Build dummies:

```
lb = LabelBinarizer()
X_month_dummies = lb.fit_transform(month)
```

`X_month_dummies` is then:

```
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

Combine dummies with numeric features (day)

```
X = np.hstack([np.column_stack([day]), X_month_dummies])
```

Build classifier.

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)
```